# Mac OS has a folder called "Volumes" that is located at /Volumes. Is there an equivalent folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, mount

Basically, the folder "Volumes" in Mac OS is convenient because it contains both local mounted drives as well as network drive mounts. I'm wondering if there's a similar folder on Ubuntu. And if there isn't, is there another way to get the file path to a mounted network drive?

The mounted drive has an smb address, but I can't enter that into MATLAB's filepath system. Was wondering if there was a way to get an alternative filepath after a network drive has been mounted. The "Volumes" folder in Mac OS was my way of doing it on a Mac.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the `mount` or `findmnt` commands

Comment: Have a look at `/mnt` and `/media`